# SIPp - How to generate a random number in SIPp scenario?

Tags: random, sipp

Currently, I need to run SIPp scenario to simulate a large of call for loading test.
In the script of the caller, after receiving 200 OK message and before sending BYE message, I need to pause a duration to simulate for call duration as follows:

Caller:

Invite ------------->

...

200 OK <----------

ACK    -------------->

**pause milliseconds="xxx"**

BYE    -------------->

I need to generate random value for **XXX** to simulate for the different call durations which is similar to real calls.

I tried to generate random values in .csv file and get these values into caller script, but it's not successful. I get an error like this:
"Pause milliseconds, ... is not a floating point number!"

How can I generate a random value in a SIPp script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SIPp reference document](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.pdf), which you may find a useful document for your future SIPp needs:

`<pause distribution=>` Indicates which statistical distribution to use
to determine the length of the pause. Without
GSL, you may use uniform or fixed. With
GSL, normal, exponential, gamma, lambda,
lognormal, negbin, (negative binomial), pareto,
and weibull are available. Depending on the
distribution you select, you must also supply
distribution specific parameters.
The following examples show the various types
of distributed pauses:
• `<pause distribution="fixed" value="1000" />` pauses for 1
second.
• `<pause distribution="uniform" min="2000" max="5000"/>` pauses
between 2 and 5 seconds.
The remaining distributions require GSL. In
general the parameter names were chosen to
be as consistent with Wikipedia's distribution
description pages.
• `<pause distribution="normal" mean="60000" stdev="15000"/>` provides a normal pause with a mean of
60 seconds (i.e. 60,000 ms) and a standard
deviation of 15 seconds. The mean and
standard deviation are specified as integer
milliseconds.